# How to limit total posts in pagination in wordpress admin area?

Tags: wordpress, pagination, posts

I have a lot of posts on my Wordpress site, about 200k+.
I want to limit total posts in the admin area when i go in Posts->All posts i want not see all 200 000 posts with pagination. Just for example only 200 latest.
I know this limitation can be implemented by code in function.php but can't find proper function in google :)
Can you please give me advice on where to dig :)

Comment: Possible reference to both legacy and function options - https://wpengineer.com/1030/change-admin-pagination-on-posts-pages-and-comments/

Comment: i find solutions here https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination something like this function my_post_queries( $query ) {

  if (is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){


    if(is_admin()){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
    }

    if(is_category()){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
    }

  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to the "admin area" sir, I believe the solution is far easier than you think. Its just int "Screen Options"

[image]

There is absolutely no need to insert any custom code: Just enter the number of posts to want to load per page: in the "Number of items per page:" value. This is a wp code setting. I don't see a reason to do custom coding for that.

Comment: In some cases when you have other users using the admin backend you might need to FORCE that value, but here you can just set it once and Wp will remember it in future.

Answer (score -1):

i find solutions here https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination
something like this:

```
function my_post_queries( $query ) {

  if (is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){


    if(is_admin()){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
    }

    if(is_category()){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
    }

  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );
```